# How to complete Add user function of my first Javascript application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

Currently the contact list application I am building does filter names. But I wanted to add a function to add names with an input field and a submit button.

But I am stuck at the very last point of the function. Aleast I think so :) Forgive me if I made a lot more mistakes.

Here comes the code for the new function I am building, please help me out a bit.

```
let addUserButton = document.getElementById('addUser');

addUserButton.addEventListener('click', addNewUser);

function addNewUser(){

//Get the input and save in in a variable
let newNameInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toUpperCase();

var li = "<li>" + newNameInput + "</li>"

//Safe the UL in a variable
let ul = document.getElementById('contacten');

/*Take all h5 elemtens with and class of contactIndex to
compare it to the first letter of the input to match the
H5 with a class of contactIndex*/

let contactIndex = ul.querySelectorAll('h5.contactIndex');

/*Loop to go to all the H5 with a class of contactIndex
and compare the input to it. If its the same
add it to the list else go on to the H5 with a class of contactIndex*/
for(let i = 0;i < contactIndex.length; i++){

let a = contactIndex[i];

if(a.innerHTML == newNameInput.charAt(0)){
  console.log(li);
  // Here I get stuck...? Please help :)

 }
}
```

If it matches I want to add the `newNameInput` variable. I tried a lot of different things, but I could not get it to work. Also I don't know where to append it for sure.

What am I missing here?

Here also is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.css">
 <title>Contacten app</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <h1 class="center-align">
     Mijn Contacten
   </h1>
   <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Search names...">
   <button id="addUser">Submit name</button>
   <ul id="contacten" class="collection with-header">

   <li class="collection-header">
     <h5 class="contactIndex">A</h5>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
     <a href="#">Alex</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Aron</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Anton</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Alice</a>
   </li>

   <li class="collection-header">
    <h5 class="contactIndex">B</h5>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Bianca</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Bron</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Brandon</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Brian</a>
   </li>

   <li class="collection-header">
    <h5 class="contactIndex">C</h5>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Carla</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Cindy</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Corne</a>
   </li>

   <li class="collection-header">
    <h5 class="contactIndex">D</h5>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Dirk</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Dylan</a>
   </li>
   <li class="collection-item">
    <a href="#">Dominique</a>
   </li>


  </ul>
</div>

 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now..

Not the cleanest code and the li elements doesnt get the class of collection-item, but heyy that is for later :)

```
let addUserButton = document.getElementById('addUser');

addUserButton.addEventListener('click', addNewUser);

function addNewUser(){

 //Get the input and save in in a variable
let newNameInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;

var li = "<li>" + "<a href='#'>" + newNameInput + "</a>" + "</li>";
//Safe the UL in a variable

let ul = document.getElementById('contacten');


/*Take all h5 elemtens with and class of contactIndex to
compare it to the first letter of the input to match the
H5 with a class of contactIndex*/
let contactIndex = ul.querySelectorAll('h5.contactIndex');

let all = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")

/*Loop to go to all the H5 with a class of contactIndex
and compare the input to it. If its the same
add it to the list else go on to the H5 with a class of contactIndex*/
for(let i = 0;i < contactIndex.length; i++){
let a = contactIndex[i];

if(a.innerHTML == newNameInput.charAt(0).toUpperCase()){

   a.outerHTML += li;


   }
 }

}
```

P.s. I also changed the html a bit

Answer (score 1):

### Appending

First you need to select the `<div>` with all of your contacts, in this case I suppose it's `<div id="contacten">`.

```
var contacts = document.getElementById('contacten');
```

Then you have to append your new contact to it by using this simple operation:

```
contacts.innerHTML += li;
```

This appends your li variable into the `innerHTML` property of the `#contacten` element.

**What is innerHTML?**

innerHTML property just represents the HTML inside the selected element, you can change it by just changing this property.

### Ordering

To order the elements we first define a function: `insertElement`. This function will be called every time we need to insert a new element into the DOM.

```
contacts = [];
function insertElement(name) {
    contacts.push(name);
    contacts.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        render(contacts[i]);
    }
}
```

**Why we use this function?**

Sorting elements directly inside the DOM is very difficult, because you will need to parse the parent element, sort all the children, re-render all the children. It's better to save every element into an array of elements and, sort and render them, every time you add a new element the the array.

This will be the function that renders every element to innerHTML of contacten.

```
function render(name) {
    var contacts = document.getElementById('contacten');
    contacts.innerHTML += '<li>'+name+'</li>';
}
```

Comment: Hello Syncro and thank you for helping. The var contacts I already stored in the let ul = ....     The other line of code you gave me worked. Only thing is, now the name gets added to the UL and not under the correct letter. If its a name that starts with an A, I want to at it to the                   
     <li class="collection-header">
        <h5 class="contactIndex">A</h5>
      </li>

Comment: That's a bit complicated in Vanilla JavaScript, it would be easier with a package like ReactJS, VueJS or Angular. That's because those frameworks use Virtual DOM that allows you to order elements and do massive operations on them. The best thing you can do in Vanilla JavaScript is to make an array containing all the names, and every time you insert a new name you re-render all the array by sorting the items first.

Comment: Thank you! Angular and React Iám just touching my first lessons in the codeschool.com courses. I wanted to try it JavaScript only for now. I will give it a try by storing all the names in an array and resort them after every input. How would the re-render part look so every names comes in the corresponding <li class="collection-header">? Can you add it in a new answer please?

Comment: Or can I wrap every li section from 1 li class=collection-header in a new ul and append it to the specific ul?  I already match the first letter with the h5 of the li class collection-header elements.

Comment: I edited my answer, but I suggest you to edit the question and explain what you need: sorting the elements, not only appending them.

Comment: Thank you, but I think this is a bit to much for me at this point. I will try a few more things but otherwise I will first learn a bit more and then come back to tackle the problem.  Probably with Angular or React.

Comment: It's not very hard to understand. For every entry we insert the name inside an `Array` (it's like a list of elements) and we sort that list (in alphabetical order), then in the `for()` loop, we pass every element of the list to the render function.

The render function just adds the element surrounded by `li` tag to the `#contacten` container.

Comment: Like I sad, it's my first project :) just started coding 4 weeks ago, so I will try to solve it a bit simpler or study a bit more and try to finish it a bit later when I have more knowladge